# Thumb Drive Loses Files

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have a thumb drive - a *Lexar JumpDrive FireFly 2GB* - that will lose 50-80% of the files every now and again.

It is formatted as FAT32 using "Quick Format" option.

I usually use it between Windows XP and Windows 7.

When the files are lost, the space they occupy is not recovered. It may say that I have 1GB of used space, while I may only be able to see 20MB.

I always use "Safely Remove Hardware" utility before removing the drive.

I have tried viewing the drive with the 7Zip File Manager, which usually shows hidden and system files, but 7Zip cannot see them either.

I have tried running "`attrib -h -r -s /s /d E:\*.*`" , but that did not help.

I believe, but am not certain, that the drive is more likely to lose files if I delete any files from it.

Is it a hardware problem - bad drive?

Comment: If this problem is isolated only to that one drive, I'd say it is failing and should be decommissioned. Otherwise, either one of your operating systems may have been infected by some kind of malware.

Comment: I have switched to using a different drive, but only time will tell if I get same problems.